# How to use python for signing XML node using SHA1withRSA and PKCS12 standard

Tags: python, cryptography, certificate, digital-signature, pyopenssl

I have received API and certificate that require the use of PKCS12 standard and signature obtained by hashing  using SHA1withRSA then results encoded to base64.

Bellow is how I have tried, I think I have not meet all API documentation requirements as stated above for signature generation.

I would like to receive help using python.

```
from OpenSSL import crypto
from lxml import etree
reg = etree.Element("REGDATA")
tin = etree.SubElement(reg, "TIN")
certKey = etree.SubElement(reg, "CERTKEY")
tin.text = "111111111"
certKey.text = "10TZ111111"
xmlData = etree.tostring(reg).decode('utf-8')

p12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(open("vfd_MOJAONE.pfx", 'rb').read(), certpw.encode())
x = crypto.sign(pkey=p12.get_privatekey(),data=xmlData.encode('utf-8'),digest="SHA1")
print(base64.b64encode(x).decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: SHA-1 is not considered secure anymore for signatures (see SHAttered attack). Where are you stuck? You seem to perform signature generation, although I would expect a requirement of XML-digsig, for which you need a library. I really don't get what " I think I have not use RSA." means though.

Comment: Please always include as much of the error in the question by hitting [edit]. Note that your error currently isn't mentioned at all.

Comment: Error is that a signature is invalid during API posting

Comment: Of cause but government still use it. The signature i have generated keep returning error during API post saying invalid signature.                                                                **Posted xml**                                                                                                                     <EFDMS>
       <REGDATA>
            <TIN>111111111</TIN>
            <CERTKEY>10TZ111111</CERTKEY>
        </REGDATA>
    <EFDMSSIGNATURE>generated signatature</EFDMSSIGNATURE>
</EFDMS>